# Nivo Slider not working with cs-cart website

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider, cs-cart

I am trying to install the Nivo Slider on a cs-cart based website. I have added the header code to index.tpl and the script to the script.tpl file, but when the page loads the slider does not appear at all. In firebug the images are shown in the HTML, but they are grayed out and don't appear. I'm not sure if the script is not working or what is going on. Here is a link to the page: http://biohairregrowth.com/index.php. I know this site is a total mess. It is so bad it's ridiculous. I am trying to do this for my crazy boss who refuses to do anything right. :/ Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Failed to load resource http://biohairregrowth/lib/js/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'runCart' index.php:110
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined index.php:467
Failed to load resource http://biohairregrowth/lib/js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://biohairregrowth.com/skins/jewelry/customer/images/loading.gif
Failed to load resource http://biohairregrowth/images/slider-test1.jpg
Failed to load resource http://biohairregrowth/images/slider-test2.jpg
Failed to load resource http://biohairregrowth/images/slider-test3.jpg
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'
```

This is what browser console's showing.
First, the browser can't load the Nivo's CSS. Check the path.
Same for Nivo's *.js file. Conseguence: It can't use `nivoSlider()` function.

It can't load images as well.

Check your files and paths.